# Unsigned string from a array nodejs

Tags: node.js

Maybe someone can help me.

Can someone help me with creating a unsigned string from a array in NodeJS.

I need to use secp256k1 for this (can't find any documentation on nodejs docs).

Comment: What, exactly, is an "_**unsigned string**_"? And what is "_**secp256k1**_"?  Inquiring minds want to know. Giving us a description of what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish, input, expected output, your code, and a description of what the problem is will go a long way towards allowing people here to help you.

Comment: Hello @NicholasCarey I have an array with data that need to encrypt with ecdsa (algorithm). this must give a string (encryption hash). This hash will be signed by third party and they give us a signed hash back.. (Hope i have explain it good)

Comment: Looks like recent-ish Nodes (v17+?) support that sort of encryption: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-ecdh